# Photoshop is not working on wine, some solution like minimal windows in virtulabox?

Tags: windows, wine, photoshop

terrible question, is some solution or version of OS windows just for one application, especially Adobe Photoshop 6, to virtualbox?

I tried it in wine (playonlinux). It is working, but it failed everytime I click on "Text make". I found some solutions, but it works only for old versions (13).

What is the best solution? Or is some good wine solution for PS6? I believe it is just about fonts, but I don't know what must be done to make this PS6 work 100%. Or virtualbox with some minimal W7 or XP? Is some "lean system" solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you need Photoshop and this particular text feature? Have you tried if gimp can do what you need? Or some other tool, for example LibreOffice, if you want more fonts than what you get in gimp?

Comment: Can you try to do it in www.Photopea.com ? You can open your own PSD files there, and edit text in them, too.

Comment: Hey, I like Gimp of course, but it is not for me. Photopea looks very nice, but... you know... people are massaged by M$. :) I wanna disseminate Ubuntu, this is my goal, but people are blind and lazy, they want exactly what they had. Sad.

Comment: I'm afraid that people, who want exactly what they had, want to continue with Windows (or MacOS). They will always find some difference, that they don't like in Ubuntu. But there are also people who want to test something new, and those may be ready to try Ubuntu even without Photoshop.

Comment: I believe the best solution would be a dual boot with a windows and ubuntu, so the lost performance is small in comparison with a virtual machine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Install Windows 10 as a Virtual Machine to run Photoshop in Ubuntu.

There is not a lot that you can do to Windows to make it run faster in VBox except to disable background applications and virus protection*, (if you are brave).

There are things that you can do to your Hardware, Ubuntu, VirtualBox and Photoshop to make Photoshop in a Windows guest run faster.

**Hardware:**

- Add RAM
- Add a fast SSD dedicated to Ubuntu.
- Add a faster CPU
- Add a better GPU
- Ensure Intel VT-x or AMD-V Is Enabled

**Ubuntu**

- Keep Ubuntu updated
- Use lightweight desktop alternatives
- Monitor startup apps
- Do not add unnecessary software
- Get rid of heavy startup applications
- Increase Swap Space if you can not afford RAM
- Enable Proprietary Drivers
- Clean out old files
- Reduce the default grub load time
- Install preload to speed up application load time

**VirtualBox:**

- Create your machine using a fixed size disk
- Allocate more memory
- Install Guest Additions
- Install Extension Packs
- Enabling copy paste
- Increase display memory
- Allocate more CPUs
- Ensure Intel VT-x or AMD-V Is Enabled
- Enable 2D / 3D Acceleration
- Suspend Instead of Shutting Down
- use the Intel PRO/1000 network drivers if using a network
- Some people report VirtualBox being faster, while others report VMware being faster

**Photoshop**

Set performance-related preferences

- Adjust the memory allocated to Photoshop
- Adjust cache levels
- Limit history states
- Set graphics processor (GPU) settings

Fine-tune Photoshop features for performance

- Work within file-size limitations
- Close unnecessary document windows
- Reduce patterns and brush tips in presets
- Minimize or turn off panel preview thumbnails
- Change file compatibility options
- Work in 8-bit image mode
- Turn off WYSIWYG font preview
- Reduce image resolution
- Purge the clipboard
- Use the Filter Gallery
- Drag between files rather than copy and paste
- Use layers wisely
- Save TIFF files without layers
- Don’t export the clipboard
- Disable the Libraries panel
- Disable Device Preview
- Disable Generator
- Disable Rulers
- Disable Font Preview
- Restart the Creative Cloud desktop app
- Use A Scratch Disk
- Use 64-bit Architecture

*Benchmarking with Novabench, disabling virus protection in Windows did not have any effect for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple Adoboe PhotoShop 6 apps; all are very old and do not have results for WINE shown in the [WINE apps database](https://www.winehq.org/search?q=Photoshop%206).

You can set up VirtualBox, install Windows in it, then install your Adobe app in that Virtual OS.

Comment: Yes, it is last way for me.