# What's the best way to install a very minimal Windows 10 as a Virtual Machine to run photoshop in?

Tags: virtualization, photoshop

I need to use the Creative Cloud for Photoshop, Illustrator, etc for work so I'd like to install a very minimal windows 10, in Ubuntu VirtualBox, so I can run just what's necessary so Photoshop can run as fast as possible.

Comment: https://superuser.com is the Q&A site for Windows.

Comment: You can install Virtualbox from Ubuntu Software. Not sure why this question got flagged as off topic, third party software is considered on topic.

Comment: @K7AAY As previously discussed Help Center > Asking states: Questions that you may ask: Running third-party applications on Ubuntu. Virtualbox is third party software.

Comment: @Thomas Ward : Why has this this question been closed as off-topic? Help Center clearly states that you may ask about running third-party applications on Ubuntu. Virtualbox is third party software.

Comment: Your question is “How do I install Windows 10 in VirtualBox” at its core.  That question is not an Ubuntu question.

Comment: @Thomas Ward The question is about how to run Photoshop as fast as possible in Ubuntu. There is no mystery about how to run Windows in VirtualBox. The Op has Ubuntu and needs to run Photoshop for his work. He would probably accept answers using Wine.

Comment: @psae: I see that Photoshop is on the Wine Top-10 Gold List. Perhaps you can run it from Ubuntu fastest without using Windows. Many Adobe products seem to work okay with Wine. https://appdb.winehq.org/

Comment: >  I'd like to install a very minimal windows 10, in Ubuntu VirtualBox <  This is from **your question** - **that's not the same as what you were asking here in comments**.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Original question did not specify 'Ubuntu Virtualbox' as you can see when you check edit history. "The question is about how to run Photoshop as fast as possible in Ubuntu" is not what the original request was. Therefore, I judged it off-topic.

Comment: @K7AAY ; I edited the question to state the obvious. The title states Virtual Machine, The forum is Ask **Ubuntu**, Why would we assume the Op is interested in a Windows VM running on a Windows Machine? That would be dense. Give the Op credit for a little intelligence. There are a quite few older questions in Ask Ubuntu about running Photoshop in a virtual machine that have not been flagged off-topic. Do you remember this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206875/photoshop-is-not-working-on-wine-some-solution-like-minimal-windows-in-virtulab . We should try to be consistent in our flagging.

Comment: @Thomas Ward : If you Add "@C.S.Cameron" to your comment I will see it. This is not my question, I simply think it is a valid question and don't think it should have been flagged off-topic. It is obvious that the Op wants to run Photoshop as fast as possible in Ubuntu. He does not want to run it in a Windows VM running in Windows. This question concerns running third party software in Ubuntu which is on-topic. A LibreOffice question is not off-topic because it mentions Word files. Search Photoshop + Virtualbox. There are many questions similar to this one, that have not been flagged off-topic.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron take this discussion to Meta please - this type of discussion requires community involvement and review as well and at this point, a meta thread discussing whether to reopen or not is warranted.

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest version of [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)

> Add the following line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. According to
>   your distribution, replace '' with 'eoan', 'bionic', 'xenial',
>   'buster', 'stretch', or 'jessie' (older versions of VirtualBox
>   supported different distributions):

```
`deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian <mydist> contrib`
```

For example, for `eoan`:

- Create new file:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
  ```

  Paste the next into it:

  ```
  deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian eoan contrib
  ```

  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- `wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -`
- `wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -`
- Install virtualbox

  ```
  sudo apt install virtualbox-6.1
  ```
- Download [Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) and [install it](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26217_01/E26796/html/qs-create-vm.html)

[Newer version of virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog) supports newer kernels and has a lot of fixes.

Comment: The answer would be better if it explained the benefit of using upstream latest Vbox instead of the quite good version that is already in the Ubuntu repositories.