# Ubuntu on Windows 10 (from Microsoft Store) installed but failed on Launch

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

Ubuntu on Windows 10 (from Microsoft Store) installed but failed on Launch with error 0x8007019e'; error message says Windows Subsystem for Linux optional component is not enabled. How?

Comment: I have been told, (but don't agree) that anything running in Windows is Off-Topic because it requires specialized Windows knowledge. https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18984/third-party-software-where-do-we-draw-the-line-on-on-topic and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1214611/whats-the-best-way-to-install-a-very-minimal-windows-10-as-a-virtual-machine-to#comment2041857_1214611

Answer (score 0):

You should enable window subsystem Linux.
Open PowerShell as Administrator and run:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
```

restart your computer when prompted.
then Ubuntu on Windows 10 from Microsoft Store